# Wine - cups-bsd but it is not going to be installed and more

Tags: 14.04, wine

On a Ubuntu 14.04 server

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

**command not found:** add-apt-repository

I have to run

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
```

Retype and now is all ok:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

After I type:

```
sudo apt-get install -y wine1.7 winetricks
```

but I have this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.34-0ubuntu1~ppa1) but it is not installable
           Recommends: cups-bsd but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: gnome-exe-thumbnailer but it is not going to be installed or
                       kde-runtime but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-droid but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-liberation but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-horai-umefont but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-unfonts-core but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-wqy-microhei
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

apt-get updade or similar not works, returns me same errors. how Can install or compile manually missing package?

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable x86 architecture for multiarch packages:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```